# How do I prevent loading of an external resource while preventing the “Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document'” error?

Tags: javascript, html, resources, loading, external

I want to defer loading of external resources until my web page is loaded, so I tried the good ol’ “defer” operator

```
<script src="//assets.adobedtm.com/aaabbbcccddd/satelliteLib-680156eb19277c7ad2206ff3fac1c250f6d6214c.js" defer></script>
```

The reason I do this is because I don’t want rendering of my page to be slow or blocked if the external resource doesn’t exist or there are problems contacting that web site.  This is an external file from Adobe that I don’t control.  Unfortunately, adding this directive on Chrome gives the following error in the console …

```
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

Does anyone know a way that I can load this file at the end without blocking rendering of my page if the resource doesn’t load AND prevent the above error?

Comment: After a page has loaded, `document.write( whatever)`  _replaces_ the entire contents of a document rather than appending to it. It seems Chrome flags attempting to do so from a deferred script as an error and the Adobe script is using `document.write` Would loading the script into an iframe help in anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a solution: [Postscribe](http://krux.github.io/postscribe/). It seems to do the trick:

```
<body>
  <div id="blah"><!-- document.write() content gets inserted here --></div>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      postscribe('#blah', '<script src="http://url/to/script.js"><\/script>');
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

No more Chrome error!

---

*Edit*: I've removed my original, non-working answer (which used code from this [huge script loading guide](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/#toc-dom-rescue)) to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed I still get the same error.  So shoudl I disregard your answer entirely?

Comment: I've updated my answer again - hopefully this works for you.

Comment: I cut and pasted your answer, replacing only the "src" part and got thsi error, "postscribe.js:689 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'postscribe' of null".  Should I replace '#blah' with something?

Comment: Yes, that should be the id of an element where you want `document.write()` output to be inserted.